# Is a collections of all continuous functions defined on [0,1] of a greater cardinality than c?

Tags: real-analysis

In a book from Micheal Searcoid called: 'Metric spaces'I found this statement:
a collections of all continuous functions defined on [0,1] is of a greater cardinality than c.
But it is not shown
How can one show it?
Is it true?
I found some topics also here, where it is proved, that the cardinality of all continuous functions on R is of the same cardinality as R itself.
Thank you
Greetings Eu2718